# Select all data not in Top 'n' as 'Other'

Tags: sql, sql-server-2005

I hope somebody may be able to point out where i'm going wrong here but i've been looking at this for the last 30 minutes and not gotten anywhere with it.

I have a temporary table that is populated with data, the front end application cannot do any logic for me so please excuse the ugly case statement logic in the table.

The user is happy with the resultset brought back as I get the top 10 records. They have now decided they want to see a group of the remaining countries (all rows not in the top 10) as 'Other'.

I have tried to create a grouping of countries not in the top 10 but it's not working, I was planning on UNION'ing this result to the top 10 results.

```
SELECT c.Country, count(*) AS 'Total_Number_of_customers', COALESCE(ili.new_customers,0) AS 'New_Customers', COALESCE(ilb.existing_first,0) AS 'Existing_First_Trans', COALESCE(ilc.existing_old,0) AS 'Existing_Prev_Trans'
FROM #customer_tmp c 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT z.country, count(*) AS 'new_customers' FROM #customer_tmp z where z.customer_type='New_Customer' group by z.country)ili ON ili.country = c.country
LEFT JOIN (SELECT zy.country, count(*) AS 'existing_first' FROM #customer_tmp zy where zy.customer_type='Existing_Customer' AND zy.first_transaction=1 group by zy.country)ilb ON ilb.country = c.country
LEFT JOIN (SELECT zx.country, count(*) AS 'existing_old' FROM #customer_tmp zx where zx.customer_type='Existing_Customer' AND zx.first_transaction=0 group by zx.country)ilc ON ilc.country = c.country
GROUP BY c.country, ili.new_customers, ilb.existing_first, ilc.existing_old
ORDER BY 2 DESC
```

Here is the SQL that I use to get results from my table.

For reference, each row in my temporary table contains a customer ID, the date they were created and their customer type, which is specific to what i'm trying to achieve.

Hopefully this is a simple problem and i'm just being a bit slow..

Many thanks in Adv.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yup; EXCEPT, or maybe add a row number to your query and then select by that:

```
SELECT * FROM (

SELECT c.Country, count(*) AS 'Total_Number_of_customers', 
row_number() OVER (ORDER BY COUNT(*) DESC) AS 'r',
COALESCE(ili.new_customers,0) AS 'New_Customers', COALESCE(ilb.existing_first,0) AS 'Existing_First_Trans', COALESCE(ilc.existing_old,0) AS 'Existing_Prev_Trans'
FROM #customer_tmp c 
LEFT JOIN (SELECT z.country, count(*) AS 'new_customers' FROM #customer_tmp z where z.customer_type='New_Customer' group by z.country)ili ON ili.country = c.country
LEFT JOIN (SELECT zy.country, count(*) AS 'existing_first' FROM #customer_tmp zy where zy.customer_type='Existing_Customer' AND zy.first_transaction=1 group by zy.country)ilb ON ilb.country = c.country
LEFT JOIN (SELECT zx.country, count(*) AS 'existing_old' FROM #customer_tmp zx where zx.customer_type='Existing_Customer' AND zx.first_transaction=0 group by zx.country)ilc ON ilc.country = c.country
GROUP BY c.country, ili.new_customers, ilb.existing_first, ilc.existing_old
ORDER BY 2 DESC

) sub_query WHERE sub_query.r >= 10
```

This may be more flexible, as you can run one query and then divide the results up into "top ten" and "the rest" quite easily.

(This is equivalent to bobs' answer; I guess we were working on this at exactly the same time!)

Answer (score 3):

Use the [`EXCEPT` operator in SQL Server](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms188055%28v=SQL.90%29.aspx):

```
SELECT <fields>
FROM <table>
WHERE <conditons>
EXCEPT
<Query you want excluded>
```

Answer (score 2):

Here's an approach using common table expressions (CTE)

```
WITH CTE AS
    (
    SELECT c.Country, count(*) AS 'Total_Number_of_customers', COALESCE(ili.new_customers,0) AS 'New_Customers', COALESCE(ilb.existing_first,0) AS 'Existing_First_Trans', COALESCE(ilc.existing_old,0) AS 'Existing_Prev_Trans'
        , ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY count(*) DESC) AS sequence
    FROM #customer_tmp c 
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT z.country, count(*) AS 'new_customers' FROM #customer_tmp z where z.customer_type='New_Customer' group by z.country)ili ON ili.country = c.country
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT zy.country, count(*) AS 'existing_first' FROM #customer_tmp zy where zy.customer_type='Existing_Customer' AND zy.first_transaction=1 group by zy.country)ilb ON ilb.country = c.country
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT zx.country, count(*) AS 'existing_old' FROM #customer_tmp zx where zx.customer_type='Existing_Customer' AND zx.first_transaction=0 group by zx.country)ilc ON ilc.country = c.country
    GROUP BY c.country, ili.new_customers, ilb.existing_first, ilc.existing_old
    )

SELECT *
FROM CTE
WHERE sequence > 10
ORDER BY sequence
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT  country, COUNT(*) cnt, SUM(new_customer), SUM(existing_first_trans), SUM(existing_prev_trans)
FROM    (
        SELECT  CASE
                WHEN country IN
                (
                SELECT  TOP 10 country
                FROM    #customer_tmp
                ORDER BY
                        COUNT(*) DESC
                ) THEN
                        country
                ELSE    'Others'
                END AS country,
                CASE WHEN customer_type = 'New_Customer' THEN 1 END AS new_customer,
                CASE WHEN customer_type = 'Existing_Customer' AND first_transaction = 1 THEN 1 AS existing_first_trans,
                CASE WHEN customer_type = 'Existing_Customer' AND first_transaction = 0 THEN 1 AS existing_prev_trans,
        FROM    #customer_tmp
        )
GROUP BY
        country
ORDER BY
        CASE country WHEN 'Others' THEN 2 ELSE 1 END, cnt DESC
```